# Get values from useEffect hook and display in React's functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm a newbie to React. Trying to get location coordinates in a page and want to display the latitude and longitude but not sure how to get the value from `getCurrentPostion` function which is being called in `useEffect` hook here. Could anyone please help?

Here's a gist of my code.

```
const getCurrentPosition = async () => {
  const {
    coords: { latitude, longitude },
  } = await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
  return { latitude, longitude };
};

const TestComponent = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentPosition().then((res) => console.log('res', res));
  });
  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonContent>
        <div>Coordinates ( Yet to be displayed ) </div>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Those values should live on the state somewhere. So for example:

```
const TestComponent = () => {
  const [coord, setCoords] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentPosition().then((res) => {
      setCoords(res);
    }
  });
  // Now you have access too coords here
  if (!coords) return <div>Loading..<div> // handle waiting for the request
  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonContent>
        <div>Coordinates { coords.latitude } { coords.longitude } </div>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};
```

Comment: Could you please tell what is `coords` here. Are you referring to the one in `const [coord, setCoords]` ?

Comment: that's right, useState returns an array with two elements, the state (coord in this case) and a way to update it (setCoords). I'm using destructuring to declare those variables

Answer (score 1):

```
const TestComponent = () => {
 const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = 
useState({latitude:"", longitude:""});
const getCurrentPosition = async () => {
  const {
    coords: { latitude, longitude },
  } = await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
  setCoordinates({latitude, longitude})
};
  useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentPosition();
  });
  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonContent>
        <div>Coordinates {coordinates.latitude}</div>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};
```